# Find the derivative of y with respect to the given independent variable

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, exponentiation

Find the derivative of y with respect to the given independent variable:

$y = 3^{-x} \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} y' = 3^{-x} \cdot (-1) \cdot \ln 3 $

This is my teacher's solution. I don't understand what he did. Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher implicitly wrote the function $y$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
y &=& 3^{-x} \\
  &=& e^{-x \ln 3}
\end{eqnarray}
From which the derivative is straightforward
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dy}{dx} &=& - \ln 3 . e^{-x \ln 3} \\
              &=& (-1).3^{-x}.\ln 3  
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Equivalently, you can write $y = 3^{-x} \implies \ln y = \ln 3^{-x} = -x \ln 3$ and use the chain rule on both sides (implicit differentiation).

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable an idea too :-)

Answer (score 1):

HINT to solve:

\begin{equation}
y=3^{-x} => e^{\ln(3^{-x})} => e^{(-x)\ln(3)}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have $$y=a^{f(x)}$$ Take logarithms of both sides $$\log(y)=f(x) \log(a)$$ Exponentiate $$y=e^{f(x) \log(a)}$$ Now, compute the derivative $$y'=f'(x)\log(a)e^{f(x) \log(a)}$$ Replace again $e^{f(x) \log(a)}$ by $a^{f(x)}$ and get $$y'=f'(x)\log(a) a^{f(x)}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score -1):

use this standard result$$\frac{d a^x}{dx}= a^xln(a)$$
and apply chain rule